# How to select one to many relationship data in PHP PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

I have total 3 tables in PHPMyAdmin:

1. **Movies**: `tmdb_movies`
2. **Cast**: `cast`. Foreign key is `cast_tmdb_id` for table `tmdb_movies` column `tmdb_id` [screenshot](http://prntscr.com/foclol)
3. **Genres**: `genres`. Foreign key is `genres_tmdb_id` for table `tmdb_movies` column `tmdb_id` [screenshot](http://prntscr.com/focl76)

I want to output the following fields:

- `movie_title` column from `tmdb_movies` table
- all `genres_name` rows from `genres` table
- all `cast_name` rows from `cast` table.

What is the smallest command to select and echo data? I am not familiar with the `join` command in SQL.

This is my current code

```
<?php 

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT tmdb_movies.*, GROUP_CONCAT(genres_name) as genres_name
    FROM tmdb_movies JOIN genres ON tmdb_movies.tmdb_id=genres.cast_tmdb_id
    GROUP BY tmdb_movies.cast_tmdb_id, tmdb_movies.tmdb_id, tmdb_movies.movie_title");

         // Then fire it up
         $stmt->execute();
         // Pick up the result as an array
         $result = $stmt->fetchAll();

        // Now you run through this array in many ways, for example
         foreach ($result as $row) {
        print "".$row["movie_title"]." ".$row["genres_name"] ."   ".$row["cast_name"] ."<br/>";
    }


    ?>
```

Comment: Are you getting an error with your current code? If so, what is the error message?

Comment: Looks like `ON tmdb_movies.tmdb_id=genres.cast_tmdb_id` should be `ON tmdb_movies.tmdb_id=genres.genres_tmdb_id`.

Comment: `Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'tmdb_movies.genres_tmdb_id' in 'group statement' in `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT tmdb_movies.movie_title, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT genres.genres_name SEPARATOR ', ') AS genres_names, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT cast.cast_name SEPARATOR ', ') AS cast_name
                    FROM tmdb_movies
                    JOIN genres ON tmdb_movies.tmbd_id=genres.genres_tmdb_id
                    JOIN cast ON cast.cast_tmdb_id=tmdb_movies.tmbd_id
                    GROUP BY tmdb_movies.movie_title
                    ORDER BY tmdb_movies.movie_title
```

Explainations :

GROUP_CONCAT => Concat fields from different row in one field

JOIN => you make two table correspond by their key

GROUP BY => group data per those fields

I've done the query I could without actually seeing your tables, so you might want to adapt it if it doesn't work on first try.